# 17 K Ohm resistor for Garmin Nuvi GPS cord

Tags: resistors

I'm just looking with someone please tell me what is the how many bands and what is the color code for a 17 K Ohm resistor for a Garmin nuvi 1300 GPS cord I'm making my own cord and I have all the parts I just I just don't know I don't have a resistor I'm looking for the color code for the resistor I'm just doing it out of parts I have laying around the house please thank you

Comment: your sentence structure sucks

Comment: Search for "resistor colour bands".

Comment: Closing this mess.  First, Kelvin-Ohms is not a relevant unit here.  Second, that runon "sentence" would be too much trouble to try to make sense of.

Answer (score 1):

17k seems odd, maybe a 12k and a 5k in series, or a 15k and a 2k. It would be easier if you looked up a [resistor color chart](https://www.digikey.com/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-resistor-color-code-4-band) and compared to see what you have. You don't have to use one resistor, you can use more than one in series to add up to the value you need.

Comment: Degrees Kelvin is not a meaningful measure of a resistor.  Ping me when fixed, and I'll undo the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

[image: 17k Ohm]

See also: [Digi-Key resistor calculator](https://www.digikey.com/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-resistor-color-code-4-band)

Or type “resistor color code” into Google.